# How to find optimal policy to maximise a desired resource over time?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling, simulation

Each week, we can decide to do a hunt or skip it. Starting at week $1$, the available reward from that hunt is a yellow shard, then a blue shard, then a red shard, repeating in that order (so e.g. week $4$ would be the second opportunity to obtain a yellow shard).

If we do a hunt, there is a base probability of $0.2$ that the shard is "tau-forged." If we do not obtain a tau-forged shard, then this probability increases by $0.2$, continuing until we obtain a tau-forged shard, at which point it resets to the base of $0.2$.

I'd like to determine a policy, based on the current available shard and tau-forged probability, to maximise the number of **red tau-forged shards** obtained over a potentially infinite time.

It is straightforward to write a simulation to determine the expected number of red tau-forged shards for a given policy, but given the number of potential policies, it seems more feasible to model this as a Markov decision process.

The state space should be $\{\text{yellow}, \text{blue}, \text{red}\}\times\{0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1\}$ and the action space $\{0,1\}$. The reward for each state/action pair would be $0$ for all transitions aside from those that transition into $(\text{yellow},0.2)$ - which would be when a red tau-forged shard is obtained.

From here, given a discount factor $0<\gamma<1$, we should be able to use an algorithm such as Bellman's value iteration to determine an optimal policy. It's been some time since I've studied MDP though, so I wanted to confirm this is a suitable (and computationally tractable) way of approaching this problem before proceeding to complete and solve the model.

(And of course, if anything is unclear about the question, feel free to ask and I will clarify to the best of my ability.)

Comment: Is there any cost to hunting?  If not, why is "hunt every day" not the optimal policy?

Comment: @user6247850 We only care about success on red days, and hunting on other days could reduce the probability of success; e.g. in the state (blue, 1), the optimal action is to not hunt.

Comment: Indeed the only cost of a hunt is the opportunity cost - @Adam gave a great example.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood how the colors worked - I thought the color only cycled when we hunted.

Comment: Isn't it the case that not all transitions into yellow, 0.2 are rewarding? If you are in red, 0.2 and don't hunt, then you transition into yellow, 0.2 with no reward, right? (You'd always want to hunt, but I want to make sure I understand)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the optimal decisions are straightforward to work out by hand, leaving a more managable remainder to optimize.

We should always hunt if a red shard is available. We might get a tau-forged one, and if we don’t, the probability to get one will increase, so this is win-win.

If another colour is available, we should always hunt when the probability is $0.2$ (since it might increase and can’t decrease) and never hunt if the probability is $1$ (since it will certainly decrease, without gain).

That settles $9$ of the $15$ decisions to be made, leaving $6$.

It seems very likely that the optimal strategy for an arbitrary discount factor $\gamma$ will turn out to be the short-term strategy for $\gamma\to0$, so let’s work that out and then check whether it’s self-consistent for $\gamma\gt0$.

For $\gamma\to0$, all we care about is whether we get a tau-forged red shard the next time a red shard is available.

In a blue week with probability $p\lt1$ to obtain a tau-forged shard, the probability of getting a tau-forged red shard next week is $p$ if we don’t hunt and $p\cdot0.2+(1-p)\cdot(p+0.2)=0.2+p-p^2$ if we hunt. Thus, we should hunt if $0.2-p^2\gt0$, that is, if $p\lt\sqrt{0.2}\approx0.45$. So in a blue week, we hunt at $p=0.2$ and $p=0.4$, and then our success probability is $0.2+0.2-0.2^2=0.36$ and $0.2+0.4-0.4^2=0.44$, respectively, and we don’t hunt at $p=0.6$, $0.8$ or $1$.

In a yellow week, things are only slightly more complicated.

At $p=0.4$, if we don’t hunt our success probability in the blue week will be $0.44$. If we do hunt, it will be $0.36$ with probability $0.4$ and $0.6$ with proability $0.6$, for a total of $0.4\cdot0.36+0.6\cdot0.6=0.504\gt0.44$, so we should hunt.

At $p=0.6$ or $0.8$, if we don’t hunt our success probability will be $p$. If we do hunt, it will be $0.36$ with probability $p$ and $p + 0.2$ with probability $1-p$, for a total of $p\cdot0.36+(1-p)\cdot(p+0.2)$, which is less than $p$ in both cases; so we shouldn’t hunt.

So the optimal strategy for $\gamma\to0$ is actually quite simple: Always hunt in red weeks, and hunt at $p=0.2$ and $p=0.4$ in yellow and blue weeks.

We don’t need a Markov chain with all $15$ states – we’re only interested in what happens in the red weeks, so we can build the transition matrix for the $5$ red states by multiplying the three transition matrices from one red week to the next:

$$
\vec p\to
\pmatrix{
0.2&0.4\\
0.8\\
&0.6&1\\
&&&1\\
&&&&1}^2
\pmatrix{
0.2&0.4&0.6&0.8&1\\
0.8\\
&0.6\\
&&0.4\\
&&&0.2}\vec p
=\pmatrix{
0.136&0.144&0.216&0.288&0.36\\
0.288&0.064&0.096&0.128&0.16\\
0.576&0.792&0.288&0.384&0.48\\
&&0.4\\
&&&0.2
}\vec p
$$

([Wolfram|Alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0.2%2C0.4%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0.8%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0.6%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%5E2%20*%20%7B%7B0.2%2C0.4%2C0.6%2C0.8%2C1%7D%2C%7B0.8%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0.6%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0.4%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0.2%2C0%7D%7D&dataset=)). The stationary distribution (the eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$) is

$$
\frac1{75409}\pmatrix{15625\\10500\\33300\\13320\\2664}\;.
$$

Thus, the expected number of tau-forged red shards obtained per red week is

$$
\frac1{75409}\pmatrix{0.2&0.4&0.6&0.8&1}\pmatrix{15625\\10500\\33300\\13320\\2664}=\frac{40625}{75409}\approx0.539\;.
$$

Now, to check whether our strategy is optimal for all discount factors $\gamma$, we need to compute the expected value at $\gamma$ and check the six decisions in the yellow and blue weeks. (I’ll use $\gamma$ to refer to the discount factor from one red week to the next; if you want it to refer to individual weeks, you need to replace it by $\gamma^3$.) The expected values at $\gamma$ for the five states are (up to some rounding errors in the [Wolfram|Alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B0.2%2C0.4%2C0.6%2C0.8%2C1%7D%20*%20%7B%7B1-0.136x%2C-0.144x%2C-0.216x%2C-0.288x%2C-0.36x%7D%2C%20%7B-0.288x%2C1-0.064x%2C-0.096x%2C-0.128x%2C-0.16x%7D%2C%20%7B-0.576x%2C-0.792x%2C1-0.288x%2C-0.384x%2C-0.48x%7D%2C%20%7B0.%2C%200.%2C-0.4x%2C1%2C%200.%7D%2C%20%7B0.%2C%200.%2C%200.%2C-0.2x%2C1%7D%7D%5E%28-1%29&dataset=)):

$$
\pmatrix{0.2&0.4&0.6&0.8&1}\left(1-\gamma\pmatrix{
.136&0.144&0.216&0.288&0.36\\
.288&0.064&0.096&0.128&0.16\\
.576&0.792&0.288&0.384&0.48\\
&&0.4\\
&&&0.2
}\right)^{-1}
=
\frac{\pmatrix{
0.2 + 0.3904 \gamma + 0.24576 \gamma^2 + 0.087552 \gamma^3 + 0.012288 \gamma^4
\\
0.4 + 0.3344 \gamma + 0.16896 \gamma^2 + 0.035712 \gamma^3 - 0.003072 \gamma^4
\\
0.6 + 0.2816 \gamma + 0.0595202 \gamma^2 - 0.00512004 \gamma^3
\\
0.8 + 0.1488 \gamma - 0.0128 \gamma^2
\\
1 - 0.064 \gamma
}^\top}{1 - 0.488 \gamma - 0.329216 \gamma^2 - 0.144077 \gamma^3 - 0.034775 \gamma^4 - 0.00393216 \gamma^5}\;.
$$

The denominator is irrelevant, since we just want to compare different linear combinations of these values. For each of the six non-obvious decisions (yellow and blue weeks with $p=0.4$, $0.6$ or $0.8$), we need to check whether the difference in expected value between our decision and the alternative is positive for $0\lt\gamma\lt1$. The differences between the probability vectors in the next red week for the six decisions are (first yellow, then blue):

$$
\pmatrix{-0.32\\0.32\\0\\0\\0},\pmatrix{-0.12\\-0.48\\1\\-0.4\\0},\pmatrix{-0.16\\-0.64\\0\\1\\-0.2},\pmatrix{0.4\\-1\\0.6\\0\\0},\pmatrix{-0.6\\0\\1\\-0.4\\0},\pmatrix{-0.8\\0\\0\\1\\-0.2}\;.
$$

We need to take the dot product of each of these with the above vector of expected values (without the denominator). Here are the corresponding Wolfram|Alpha plots: [yellow at $0.4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20-0.32%20*%20%280.2%20%2B%200.3904%20x%20%2B%200.24576%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.087552%20x%5E3%20%2B%200.012288%20x%5E4%29%20%2B%200.32%20*%20%280.4%20%2B%200.3344%20x%20%2B%200.16896%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.035712%20x%5E3%20-%200.003072%20x%5E4%29%20for%20x%3D0..1&dataset=), [yellow at $0.6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%200.064%20%2B%200.01472%20x%20-%200.0459518%20x%5E2%20-%200.032768%20x%5E3%20for%20x%3D0..1), [yellow at $0.8$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-0.16%20*%20%280.2%20%2B%200.3904%20x%20%2B%200.24576%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.087552%20x%5E3%20%2B%200.012288%20x%5E4%29%20-%200.64%20*%20%280.4%20%2B%200.3344%20x%20%2B%200.16896%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.035712%20x%5E3%20-%200.003072%20x%5E4%29%20%2B%20%280.8%20%2B%200.1488%20x%20-%200.0128%20x%5E2%29%20-%200.2%20*%20%281-0.064%20x%29), [blue at $0.4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.4%20*%20%280.2%20%2B%200.3904%20x%20%2B%200.24576%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.087552%20x%5E3%20%2B%200.012288%20x%5E4%29%20-%20%280.4%20%2B%200.3344%20x%20%2B%200.16896%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.035712%20x%5E3%20-%200.003072%20x%5E4%29%20%2B%200.6%20%280.6%20%2B%200.2816%20x%20%2B%200.0595202%20x%5E2%20-%200.00512004%20x%5E3%29), [blue at $0.6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-0.6%20*%20%280.2%20%2B%200.3904%20x%20%2B%200.24576%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.087552%20x%5E3%20%2B%200.012288%20x%5E4%29%20%2B%20%280.6%20%2B%200.2816%20x%20%2B%200.0595202%20x%5E2%20-%200.00512004%20x%5E3%29%20-%200.4%20%280.8%20%2B%200.1488%20x%20-%200.0128%20x%5E2%29), [blue at $0.8$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20-0.8%20*%20%280.2%20%2B%200.3904%20x%20%2B%200.24576%20x%5E2%20%2B%200.087552%20x%5E3%20%2B%200.012288%20x%5E4%29%20%2B%20%280.8%20%2B%200.1488%20x%20-%200.0128%20x%5E2%29%20%20-0.2%20%281%20-%200.064x%29%20for%20x%3D0..1). As expected, the difference is positive for $0\lt\gamma\lt1$.

Thus, independent of the discount factor, the optimal strategy is to hunt except if $p\ge0.6$ in yellow and blue weeks. In equilibrium, the expected discounted value of the tau-forged red shards obtained by this strategy is

$$
\frac1{1 - 0.488 \gamma - 0.329216 \gamma^2 - 0.144077 \gamma^3 - 0.034775 \gamma^4 - 0.00393216 \gamma^5}\cdot\\[20pt]
\pmatrix{
0.2 + 0.3904 \gamma + 0.24576 \gamma^2 + 0.087552 \gamma^3 + 0.012288 \gamma^4
\\
0.4 + 0.3344 \gamma + 0.16896 \gamma^2 + 0.035712 \gamma^3 - 0.003072 \gamma^4
\\
0.6 + 0.2816 \gamma + 0.0595202 \gamma^2 - 0.00512004 \gamma^3
\\
0.8 + 0.1488 \gamma - 0.0128 \gamma^2
\\
1 - 0.064 \gamma
}^\top\cdot\frac1{75409}\pmatrix{15625\\10500\\33300\\13320\\2664}
\\
=\frac{40625 + 20800 \gamma + 7425.6 \gamma^2 + 1572.48 \gamma^3 + 159.744 \gamma^4}{75409\left(1 - 0.488 \gamma - 0.329216 \gamma^2 - 0.144077 \gamma^3 - 0.034775 \gamma^4 - 0.00393216 \gamma^5\right)}\;.
$$

For your initial state, where we start in a yellow week with $p=0.2$, we reach the first red week with a probability vector $(0.36,0.16,0.48,0,0)^\top$, so the discounted value of the tau-forged red shards obtained is

$$
\frac1{1 - 0.488 \gamma - 0.329216 \gamma^2 - 0.144077 \gamma^3 - 0.034775 \gamma^4 - 0.00393216 \gamma^5}\cdot\\[20pt]
\pmatrix{
0.2 + 0.3904 \gamma + 0.24576 \gamma^2 + 0.087552 \gamma^3 + 0.012288 \gamma^4
\\
0.4 + 0.3344 \gamma + 0.16896 \gamma^2 + 0.035712 \gamma^3 - 0.003072 \gamma^4
\\
0.6 + 0.2816 \gamma + 0.0595202 \gamma^2 - 0.00512004 \gamma^3
\\
0.8 + 0.1488 \gamma - 0.0128 \gamma^2
\\
1 - 0.064 \gamma
}^\top\cdot\pmatrix{0.36\\0.16\\0.48\\0\\0}
\\
=\frac{0.424 + 0.329216 \gamma + 0.144077 \gamma^2 + 0.034775 \gamma^3 + 0.00393216 \gamma^4}{1 - 0.488 \gamma - 0.329216 \gamma^2 - 0.144077 \gamma^3 - 0.034775 \gamma^4 - 0.00393216 \gamma^5}\;.
$$

(This is with $\gamma$ referred to red weeks only; to get the value discounted per week, starting from the initial yellow week, replace $\gamma$ by $\gamma^3$ and multiply by $\gamma^2$ for the two weeks before the first red week.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; unfortunately I just found out that the problem at hand was changed, and the probability increase for receiving a non tau-forged shard is separate per shard shard colour. So the question is moot at this point, I'm afraid :(